# Is this database in third normal form/3NF?

Tags: sql, database-normalization, 3nf

I know this is probably a stupid question to some but I'm required to have this database in 3NF but know very little about normalisation as our teacher has not covered it. Could someone give me a simple yes or no answer as to whether it is in 3NF and if it is not, suggest any changes. Thanks.

[image: The Database]

Comment: Please read your textbook & show & justify your work following it. (Dozens are online free in pdf.) Because this just asks to rewrite your textbook & do your homework. Google 'stackoverflow homework'. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer No.  Google transitive dependencies, or even just Google 3NF?

Why is this the case?  Because you have some columns that are dependant on other columns in the same table, where those columns aren't part of the primary key.

For example, in your Customer Table you have Postcode and Town, but there is a relationship between the two, i.e. you couldn't have a Postcode for Paris without also having a Town of Paris.  This is very weak transitive dependence, and most databases would have this without considering it bad practice, but I think this is enough to break 3NF.

There's another place where it's a little less clear, but I am pretty sure you break 3NF.  In your Payment Table you have Deposit Paid, Total Price, Amount Still To Pay, and Fully Paid.  There's an argument that given Total Price and Deposit Paid you could determine Amount Still to Pay.  There's a very strong argument that you could always determine Fully Paid from the other three "paid" columns.

Comment: Regarding your comment about Postcode and Town, it's not uncommon for a postcode to cover more than one city/town name.  In the US, zip codes can be reassigned, and some municipalities, when they break away from a larger city, are given that same zip code; thus, the customer might say they live in SuburbA, but the zip code databases still think that is in BigCityA. Because postcodes are not guaranteed to be 1:1, I don't think it violates normalization to retain both postalcode and city name somehow in a database.

Comment: Sorry I should have pointed out that DepositPaid and FullyPaid are boolean values as its not clear, I dont think that makes any difference anyways, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create Person table with id,title,firstname,lastname
2. You can add person_id to customerTable and employeeTable. And remove title,firstname,lastname fields from that table.
3. You can create TownTable with columns id,name and then add town_id to customerTable and emloyeeTable. Remove column town ftom that tables
4. Create contactInfoTable with columns id, contact_type_id, contact_info
5. Add contact_info_id column to employeeTable and customerTable. Delete another columns about contact info (phoneNo,email) from that tables.
6. Create contactType table woth columns id,name. Fill two rows to that table with names phone and email
7. Create personAddress table with columns id, address, town_id
8. Add personAddress_id to customerTable, employeeTable tables. Remove address,town from that tables
9. Create TownTable woth columns id,name
10. You can create userTable with columns id,employee_id,username
11. You can create passwordTable with id and user_id
12. Create user_role table with id, user_id, role_id
13. Create role_table and add id,name

Also add create_date,end_date (Date ), active(nvarchar2(1) or integer) to all your tables. And in your selects use active=1 condition.